# Move between lists open multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to create an app that moves elements between two lists. When the element in the joblist gets clicked it has to open multiple times.

*So when I click on: Open: 2 x. This elements has to move to the other list but also show up there twice.*

I have no idea how to do this and where to start. I got it so far that you can click the element and it moves to the other list. But i don't know how to multiply it by the number.

```
$scope.toB = function(item) {
    $scope.listB.push(item);
    $scope.listA.splice($scope.listA.indexOf(item), 1);
  };

  $scope.toA = function(item) {
    $scope.listA.push(item);
    $scope.listB.splice($scope.listB.indexOf(item), 1);   
  };
```

My version on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hccVnsHtRLCdQ2LxefgH?p=preview)

Here is an image that displays what I mean.

[image: This is what I mean.]

Comment: what do you mean `also show up there twice` ? do you want to duplicate the item in details list also remain in the job list ?

Comment: I added an image to show you what I mean. Hopefully this makes it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I made this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/K9SlyYkJLJjLm9QH0MqV?p=preview

so now when an item in the left list is clicked, it'll show up in the right list x times, where x is the item's `id` attribute. You can replicate the code to also clone items when clicked in the right list.

Was this anywhere near what you needed, or if not, can you explain your problem in a bit more detail?

Comment: you forget to remove mutiple item during switching from rigth to left

Comment: Thank you that is what I wanted. Sorry if I was a bit unclear ;).